# Removing border style changes page layout

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a following HTML/CSS code:

**CSS**

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: none; outline: none; }
#container {
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
#container2 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The sample page looks as I expect, i.e. the lower div (yellow) is pushed 400px down from the top border of the outer div (gray).
But, when you remove line: `border: solid 1px black;` from the style definition of `#container`, the outer div (gray) starts from the same top position as the inner div (yellow).
This happens in Firefox 3.x and Chrome.
Can someone explain why does it happen ? In my opinion, removing border style should not affect this layout at all.

Comment: For some reason your XHTML (oh dear) 1.0 Strict has got an HTML 4.01 Transitional Doctype at the top. You should probably correct that.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. It was a side effect of massive copy/paste when I was creating sample code from my real life document

Comment: It's still invalid. You can't slap "/" characters inside tags willy-nilly in HTML :)

Comment: Hope that now it's OK :-). Thanks Dave once again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Borders separate collapsing margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: Thanks for providing the clue. I have added `<br clear="both"` after the `<div id="container">` and now it works as it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Really weird. If you want to do away with the border, add a `padding: 1px` to #container, and you can remove the border without affecting the layout.

Comment: I am intrigued.  Is this the "correct" fix?  Why does this work?

Comment: This fix works. However, it's rather a workaround than a solution. The proper solution is to add `<br clear="both">` to the `#container` div. According to CSS, when there is a clearance, then vertical margins do not collapse. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How can adding a non-semantic (ie BR) element to your markup be the correct solution? There must be something else...

Answer (score 0):

The width of the border takes space, which can cause layout changes to happen.  In order to account for that, you might need to change your margins/padding by the width of the border.

Comment: i thought that was the problem too, but after looking at what's happening this is not the case, the two pages look completely different.

Answer (score 0):

If you add

> float: left;

on your #container div, then the grey box will have the same height as before you removed the "border" from your style.

Then you just need to position the box the correct place.

Hope this helps out...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you are faced with collapsing margins.
Margins are collapsed inside block formating context.
There is a way to create another context by adding `overflow: hidden;` to #container

Answer (score 0):

The reason was stated in posts above, but a proper fix I believe is as follows:

```
.TextInput
{
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
}

.TextInput:focus
{
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 133);
}
```

The above example sets a thicker border when a text box has the input. Notice that to change the border from 1 pixel to 2 pixels, the padding had to be reduced from 4 pixels to 3 pixels. Without the change to 3 pixels of padding instead of 4 pixels the text box would shift in position in the layout, causing a small 1 pixel shift in its vertical position.